# Issues with Dashboard/Control Options

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google Chart to show value vs datetime, where the graph is shown in a horizontal manner. I also want to show a ChartRangeFilter that corresponds with this chart, also in a horizontal manner. I want the top of the chart to reflect the oldest date, with bottom of the chart reflecting the newest date. This calls for me to draw the chart as such:

```
var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'LineChart',
            'containerId': 'chart_div',
            'options': {
              'width': "100%",
              'height': "100%",
              "vAxis": { "textPosition": "none", "direction": -1},
              "orientation": "vertical",
              "legend": "none"
            }
          });
```

This works fine, however the probem is with the ChartRangeFilter:

```
var chartRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
            'containerId': 'filter_div',
            'options': {
              filterColumnIndex : 0,
              ui: {
                chartType: 'LineChart',
                orientation: 'vertical',
                chartOptions: {
                  'width': "100%",
                  'height': "100%",
                  "vAxis": { "textPosition": "none", "direction": -1},
                  "orientation": "vertical",
                  "legend": "none"
                }
              }
            }
          });
```

As soon as I click on the ChartRangeFilter, the actual chart goes blank. I found the culprit to be `"direction": -1`  in the ChartRangeFilter, as getting rid of it stops the chart from going blank. However, this reverses the desired Y-Axis, leaving an undesirable disconnect in the user interface.

Is there anything I am doing wrong, or using incorrectly that would cause this error, or is it a bug? Is there anyway for me to get around this issue and show my desired results?

Edit: JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thelostdays/ZkAH4/1/

Comment: Can you put the code in a fiddle?

Comment: Sure thing, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Getting and inserting fake data took longer than expected. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/thelostdays/ZkAH4/1/

Comment: This is a bug.  Reversing the direction of the axis causes the range end values to be less than the range start values, which will always result in an empty data set.

Comment: I reported the bug on code.google.com and it has already been accepted! Thank You!